# How to get the URL for the B2C website/storeview from a B2B website/storeview/product-page

Tags: product, ce-1.9.0.1, multistore, store-view, product-urls

In one magento installation I have multiple websites, stores and storeviews.

Storeviews are used for internationalisation (i.e. NL, DE, EN etc)

Most of our productranges are available in one, maximum two B2C websites/stores.

Part of this Magento installation is one B2B (resellers) website/store (with two storeviews, one NL, one EN) where all products are listed.

Pricing in this store is hidden using [sitewards/b2bprofessional](https://github.com/sitewards/B2BProfessional), but guests (not-logged-in) are able to browse the complete catalog.

On the product pages I'd like to show not-logged-in users a link to the other website(s)/storeview(s) (just those storeviews in their language of course) in this same magento installation where they as a B2C customer should/could buy.

I've got the easy part (*"if(! Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){};"*) covered ;)

Now for the hard part: How to query Magento for the correct URL(s) of the other storeviews this product is available in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view.phtml I added the following code as a proof of concept.

Of course it needs some cleanup and I'll probably end up writing a module for this specific functionality, but I'm glad it works as expected.

**Any comments / thoughts on how to make this code cleaner/better are appreciated!**

```
<?php 
$current_website_id     = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId(); // gets current website ID
$current_locale_code    = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code'); // gets locale like nl_NL for current store  
$store_ids              = $_product->getStoreIds(); // gets all store IDs this product is available in 
$idPath                 = sprintf('product/%d', $_product->getId()); // Complete idPath for lookup in url_rewrite table 
$coreUrl                = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite'); // Load the rewrite model 

foreach ($store_ids as $store_id) { // Iterate through each storeId
    $website_id = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($store_id)->getWebsiteId(); // Get the website ID of this Store ID
    $locale     = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $store_id); // Get the Locale of this Store ID

    if ($current_website_id !== $website_id) : // We just need the URLs for OTHER websites that contain the same product ... 
        if ($current_locale_code === $locale) : // Only the URL for the SAME locale (no need to send dutch people to an English website... 
            $coreUrl->setStoreId($store_id); // Set the URL Rewrite model to the Store ID currently being processed.. 
            $coreUrl->loadByIdPath($idPath); // Load the Rewritten Url for this product/store ID
            $baseUrl = Mage::app()->getStore($store_id)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK); // get the Base URL for the store ID currently being processed 
            echo $this->__('Also available at ').$baseUrl.$coreUrl->getRequestPath(); // Echo the URL where this product is also available 
        endif; 
    endif; 
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `getStoreIds()` on your product object.  It will return an Array that you can iterate through.

If you're in catalog/product/view.phtml you can do it like this:

```
$store_ids = $_product->getStoreIds();
foreach ($store_ids as $store_id) {
     switch ($store_id) {
        case 1:
              // store id 1 action here
        break;
        case 2:
              // store id 2 action here
        break;
        case 3:
              // store id 3 action here
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx! Currently building on your answer, looks positive so far. I'll post my final code here once done.